# call real web service code in order to create pact files

Tags: pact, pact-python

can you please help me on below scenario?

i am doing poc on pact and need help on understanding the concept .
do we need to call real web service call code in order to create pact files? if yes, how to create pact files for existing API code

```
def test_HappyPath (self):
           mockurl = 'http://localhost:1234'
           expected =  {body:true}
           pact.given (
               'Given there is a valid  form'
           ).upon_receiving (
               'fetch all the info '
           ).with_request (
                'get',
               '/',headers={Authorization:'Bearer 58771381-333e-334f-9604-784'}
           ).will_respond_with(200, body=expected)
 with pact:
               result = callAPI ( mockurl )
           self.assertEqual(result, expected )

def callAPI (url):
    return requests.get ( url ).json()
```

my understanding is **callAPI** is real production web service call ? am i correct ? if yes, do you have any sample code to return requested response from real service. i am kind of stuck in this specific part to complete my POC on pact

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

`callAPI` should be the code in your consumer that is normally responsible for calling a remote API (provider). As part of your test setup, you should configure your system to point at the local mock server that Pact starts in place of the real server.

When `callAPI` is executed, it will get back a `200` with your `expected` body. You should then perform some checks that `callAPI` worked as expected.